# Sending Mail in Vb.net using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

Am using the below code to send a mail in vb.net, this code works fine with gmail but not works with rediffmail

```
Mail.Subject = "test email"
Mail.To.Add(dgr.Cells("to@xyz.com")
Mail.From = New MailAddress("from@abc.com")
Mail.Body = "Hello"
Dim attachment As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
attachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment("AttachPath")
Mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.rediffmailpro")
SMTP.EnableSsl = false
SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@.abc.com", 
"password")
SMTP.Port = 25
SMTP.Send(Mail)
```

any reason? or solution, so that I can sent mail using any Email ID

Comment: how its possible?...........may be REDIFF server is slow comapring to GMAIL.

Comment: shouldn't it be smtp.rediffmailpro.com instead of smtp.rediffmailpro?

Comment: yaaaaaaa but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.rediffmailpro.com")
```

Comment: showing the error Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable for the user sending the mail

Comment: This is an SMTP error the server will reply if that email address does not exist in the server, you should debug to see what email address are you trying to send instead of thinking there is something wrong in the way you are using the SMTP protocol.